How can I auto-level brightness, contrast, or gamma with FFmpeg?
I'm using FFmpeg to automatically process home security camera footage, and the camera produces lots of very bright or very dark footage (such as immediately after waking up or toggling its infrared lights).
If I manually inspect the footage, this might do the trick.
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "eq=brightness=0.8:contrast=2" -vframes 1 out.jpg

But I want the brightness, contrast, or gamma to be automatically calculated by the average brightness of the image.
Although the video might be very dark or light on average, it usually uses the full pixel color value range 0.0-1.0, so expanding/rescaling it to the full range with normalize has no effect:
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "normalize=independence=0" -vframes 1 out.jpg

Is there a way to filter a video so each frame has a near-50% average pixel brightness, without writing a custom FFmpeg filter in C?
